# String Only recording first word

Tags: c, string, cpu-word

I am just getting started with programming in C and am writing a cypher/decypher program.  The user is asked to type in a phrase which is stored as a char *.  Problem is the program is only storing the first word of the string and then ignores everything after it.  Here's the part of the code that fetches the string and then analyses it

```
int maincalc(int k)                         //The Calculation Function for Cyphering
{
    char *s;
    s=(char*) malloc(sizeof(100));
    printf("Please enter the phrase that you would like to code: ");  
    fscanf(stdin,"%s %99[^\n]", s);
    int i=0;
    int n=strlen(s);

    while(i<n)
    {
        if(s[i]>=65&&s[i]<=90)              //For Uppercase letters
        {
            int u=s[i];
            int c=uppercalc(u,k);
            printf("%c",c);
        }
        else if(s[i]>=97&&s[i]<=122)    //For Lowercase letters
        {
            int u=s[i];
            int c=lowercalc(u,k);
            printf("%c",c);
        }
        else 
            printf("%c",s[i]);          //For non letters
        i++;
    }
    free(s);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Just need to know what to do to get the program to acknowledge the presence of the entire string not only the first word.  Thanks

Comment: +1 for not thinking about `gets()`

Comment: I'm too new to go near gets() i don't want my computer to explode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Nope, neither one works. using fscanf doesn't wait for user input. It simply prints "Please enter the phrase..." And then quits fgets also does the same thing, program doesn't wait for an input, just prints "PLease enter..." and then quits.

In that comment, before the edit, you mentioned some previous input. My psychic debugging powers tell me that there is a newline from the previous input still in the input buffer. That would make

```
fgets(s, 100, stdin);
```

and

```
fscanf(stdin, "%99[^\n]", s);
```

immediately return because they immediately encounter the newline that signals the end of input.

You need to consume the newline from the buffer before getting more string input. You could use

```
fscanf(stdin, " %99[^\n]", s);
```

the space at the beginning of the format consumes any initial whitespace in the input buffer, or clear the input buffer

```
int ch;
while((ch = getchar()) != EOF && ch != '\n);
if (ch == EOF) {
    // input stream broken?
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

before getting the input with either `fgets` or `fscanf`.

Comment: Yes there is a previous input, an int.  But there isn't a /n anywhere in the code, after the user inputs the number (it's the cypher/decpher rot) the program continues.  I haven't specified a new line but it might be put in there by convention automatically by the program.

Comment: @shea If the user enters the number on the terminal, the programme (usually) only receives the input after the user pressed enter. That produces the newline that remains in the input buffer.

Comment: @Daniel yup that's what I thought.  Thanks.  So is the %99[/n] telling the computer to read 99 characters while ignoring the first /n?

Comment: @shea The first `'\n'` is matched by the newline from the previous input; it will also match any spaces that the user inputs at the beginning of the line. After that, the `%99[^\n]` matches up to 99 characters different from `'\n'` and stores them in `s` (then adding a 0-termnator after them). So if the user enters `"    Free beer!"`, the contents of `s` will become `"Free beer!"` without leading spaces. If you don't want that, use `fgets` and remove the newline manually.